# Prove that $L(G)$ is Eulerian if $G$ is Eulerian.

Tags: graph-theory

Prove that $L(G)$ is Eulerian if $G$ is Eulerian.

**My idea is:** If $G$ is Eulerian, then all vertices are of even degree; in other words, an even number of edges are incident on each vertex. Hence $L(G)$ has only vertices of even degree.

Where $L(G)$ denotes the line graph of $G$. The line graph of $G$ is the simple graph whose vertices are the edges of G, with $ef\in E(L(G))$ when $e$ and $f$ have a common endpoint in $G$.

Comment: looks good to me, perhaps you can explain why every vertex of $L(G)$ has even degree by saying what the degree of each vertex of $L(G)$ is explicitly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose that $G$ is simple, and that it is Eulerian. Then all of its vertices have an even degree. Consider an edge $(u, v) \in E(G)$, and its corresponding vertex in $L(G)$. It has degree

$$(\deg(u) - 1) + (\deg(v) - 1) = \deg(u) + \deg(v) - 2$$

Note that this is not necessarily true if $G$ is not simples (i.e. if it has multiple edges, for example, a graph with two nodes and two edges between them is Eulerian, but its edge graph isn't). Since $\deg(u), \deg(v)$ are both even, it follows that $\deg(u) + \deg(v) - 2$ is also even. Then, all we need to show is that this graph is connected given that $G$ itself is, which should be pretty simple: there exists a path from any edge to any other.

Comment: Since $G$ is connected, there exists a path betweenevery pair of vertices. Then by definition of line graphs, the adjacent edges of $G$ are in adjacent vertices in $L(G)$. Then there is a path between every pair of vertices in $L(G)$. Is this correct?

Comment: Yes, that's correct!